# can not require socket.so in lua

Tags: lua, luasocket

I use Lua-5.1.3 and luasocket-2.0.2.It is all right when I make the socket.so.
When I require socket.so,it failed and give me this error:

```
./socket.so:undefined symbol:luaopen_socket.
```

Because of my pool knowledge, I don't know how to handle the problem. Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: Did you compile socket.so as C++?

Comment: Do you mean you are using `require("socket.so")`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nm socket.so` to check which symbols are actually there. I suspect you will find a symbol `luaopen_socket_core` (and/or `luaopen_mime_core`), because luasocket consists of multiple Lua modules (e.g. `socket.lua`, `socket/http.lua`, ...) and two C modules (`socket/core.so` and `mime/core.so`). For `require("socket")` to work you will need at least `socket.lua` somewhere in your `package.path`.